# Xcode 7.3.1 c++ doesn't support __declspec(align(#))

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-alignment

I always used declspec(align(#)) keyword to align data and it perfectly worked until I upgraded Xcode to 7.3.1. Now I have an error "No matching function for call to "align". I can align using "attribute" keyword. But it is not supported by Visual studio. 
Anybody have such problem ? May be I missed something ?

Comment: Should be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895869/cross-platform-alignx-macro

Comment: Thank you for a useful link. But I don't understand why declspec(align()) was supported by the previous version of Xcode (I think it was 7.1.1). Was compiler changed to GCC in new version ?