# __declspec(align(#)) equivalent with i686-w64-mingw32-g++ compiler

Tags: c++

Hello I'm doing a MASM course and there is also C++ but the teacher is using Visual Studio and I'm using Linux.
In the code I'm doing there is the following instructions:

```
__declspec(align(#))
```

I have this code:

```
_desclspec(align(16))XmmVal a;
_desclspec(align(16))XmmVal b;
_desclspec(align(16))XmmVal c[2];
```

But I cannot use "align" and "_desclspec" on linux by compiling with "i686-w64-mingw32-g++" because I get an error "was not declared in this scope":

> SSEPackedIntegerArithmetic.cpp:24:16: error: ‘align’ was not declared
> in this scope    24 |     _desclspec(align(16))XmmVal a;
> |                ^~~~~ SSEPackedIntegerArithmetic.cpp:24:5: error: ‘_desclspec’ was not declared in this scope    24 |
> _desclspec(align(16))XmmVal a;
> |     ^~~~~~~~~~

How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895869/cross-platform-alignx-macro

Comment: Thanks really much ! But I still get the same error :/

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the linked answer. As of C++11 and VS2015 [you should be using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/alignment-cpp-declarations?view=msvc-170) the standard `alignas` instead of the Microsoft specific `__declspec(align)`. They are equivalent.

Comment: @HTNW Thank you so "alignas(16) XmmVal" a for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't "Windows vs. Linux" as much as "choice of compiler".

Here's the documentation for MSVC.  Note the caveat about "MSVS 2015 and later":

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/align-cpp
>
> In Visual Studio 2015 and later, use the C++11 standard `alignas`
> specifier to control alignment. For more information, see Alignment.

The equivalent to `_declspec(align(16))` for gcc would be:

> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html
>
> ```
> __attribute__((aligned (16)))
> ```

You should definitely see if your compiler supports [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas).

Comment: I am using "i686-w64-mingw32-g++" because I need to compile with MASM Assembly code